# Broadcast receiver leaked

Tags: java, android, broadcastreceiver

I am trying to send a broadcast receiver from a service and i have a issue, the receiver leak and i don't know why.

**Here is the code:**

```
public class CameraCapture extends AppCompatActivity {
    static final int REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE = 30;
    String URL;
    VolleyService mVolleyService;
    IResult mResultCallback = null;
    final String POSTREQUEST = "POSTCALL";
    Map<String, String> params;
    String token;

    BroadcastReceiver receiver;
    IntentFilter filter;
    MyReceiver reciver;

    boolean mBounded;
    GoogleLocation mlocation;



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


        token = checkForToken();
        URL = "http://10.0.2.2:3000/fotos/Tulipa";

        filter = new IntentFilter("com.myapp.LOCATION_CHANGED");
        reciver = new MyReceiver();
        registerReceiver(reciver,filter);

        String imageFilePath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/picture.jpg";
        File imageFile = new File(imageFilePath);
        Uri imageFileUri = Uri.fromFile(imageFile); // convert path to Uri

        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.CAMERA}, REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

        Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        if (intent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
            startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        Intent mIntent = new Intent(this, GoogleLocation.class);
        bindService(mIntent, mConnection, BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
    }

    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        Log.d("RESUME","RESUME");
        reciver = new MyReceiver();
        registerReceiver(reciver, filter);
    }

    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        if(reciver != null){
            unregisterReceiver(reciver);
            reciver= null;
        }

    }

    public void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        if(mBounded) {
            unbindService(mConnection);
            mBounded = false;
        }
    }


    private byte[] encodeImage(Bitmap bm) {
        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        bm.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, baos);
        byte[] b = baos.toByteArray();

        return b;
    }

    private void sendImage(byte[] b) {
        ImageStore.getInstance().setCapturedPhotoData(b);
        mlocation.getBroadcastData();

        Intent i = new Intent(CameraCapture.this, SimiliarPhotos.class);
        startActivity(i);
        finish();
        //inicialize a map with pair key value
        //params = new HashMap<String, String>();
        // Add form fields to the map
        //GoogleLocation l = new GoogleLocation(this);
        //l.getPosition();
        //Log.d("myLat",String.valueOf(l.getLat()));
        //params.put("base64", encodedImage);
        //params.put("token",token);

        //Log.d("latitudeOP",String.valueOf(l.getLat()));

        //JSONObject sendObj = new JSONObject(params);

        //initVolleyCallback();

        //mVolleyService = new VolleyService(mResultCallback, this);

        //mVolleyService.postDataVolley(POSTREQUEST, URL, sendObj);
    }

    public void showToast(String message) {
        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(this, message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
        toast.show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);

        switch (requestCode) {
            case 30: {

                if (grantResults.length > 0
                        && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                } else {

                    Toast.makeText(CameraCapture.this, "Permission denied to read your External storage", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                return;
            }
        }
    }

    void initVolleyCallback() {
        mResultCallback = new IResult() {
            @Override
            public void notifySuccess(String requestType, JSONObject response) {

            }

            @Override
            public void notifySuccess(String requestType, JSONArray response) {

            }


            @Override
            public void notifyError(String requestType, VolleyError error) {
                String body;

                if (error.networkResponse.data != null) {
                    String statusCode = String.valueOf(error.networkResponse.statusCode);
                    try {
                        body = new String(error.networkResponse.data, "UTF-8");
                        JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(body);
                        Log.d("body", String.valueOf(jsonObj.get("message")));
                        showToast(String.valueOf(jsonObj.get("message")));
                    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                        showToast("You need to connect to the internet!");
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        Log.d("json:", "problems decoding jsonObj");
                    }
                }
            }
        };
    }

    ServiceConnection mConnection = new ServiceConnection() {

        public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName name) {
            mBounded = false;
            mlocation = null;
        }

        public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName name, IBinder service) {
            mBounded = true;
            GoogleLocation.LocalBinder mLocalBinder = (GoogleLocation.LocalBinder)service;
            mlocation = mLocalBinder.getServerInstance();
        }
    };
```

as you guys can see i register the receiver 2 times, oncreate and onResume, and then i destroy it onStop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you are registering it twice. remove the code from `onCreate` and keep it only in `onResume`. Also if you are registering it in `onResume` then `unRegister` it in `onPause` to match the lifecycle events properly.

Comment: i already did that, if i do the changes like you mention it never enters the onreceive dunno why´

Comment: Well i think i know what is happening, i have a service and  inside 1 method i do the broadcast, in that activity i need to register the broadcast first and after do the connection

Comment: You have to be sure you activity is in foreground to be able to receive a broadcast registered/unregistered in `onResume`/`onPause`

Comment: Yeah, do the service connection after the receiver is registered

Comment: i thaught everytime the issue was with the broadcast, but it was with the service connection, i didn't need the broadcast :D

Answer (score 1):

Always register receiver in onStart() and unregister in onStop().

Since you registering receiver in onCreate(), you have to unregister in onDestroy() as well as there is a chance that activity ends up with only onCreate() and onDestroy() call backs.

Comment: in which scenario activity will endup in onCreate and onDestroy?

Comment: It's rare, but there is a chance. If you call finish() in onCreate(), onDestroy() of activity will be called.

Answer (score 0):

Do not forget to unregister a dynamically registered receiver by using `Context.unregisterReceiver()` method. If you forget this, the Android system reports a leaked broadcast receiver error. For instance, if you registered a receive in `onResume()` methods of your activity, you should unregister it in the `onPause()` method.